# GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository when building in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, build, gitlab

I create a pipeline on Jenkins platform, added my git repo in the configuration, but when I build the pipeline, it gave me error like this:

[image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you provide the credentials? Because the error clearly shows that it is an issue of access rights. Are you using the [checkout](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm) step for adding the configuration? Then you can add the credentials as follows

```
 steps {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: 'master']],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', relativeTargetDir: 'targetdirectoryname'],
                                [$class: 'CleanCheckout']],
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'yourcredentailID', url: 'repo_url']]])
            }
```

if you don't want to show your credentials in the code, you can use [jenkins' credentials](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me.
When changing users in Gitlab (work & personal) then you have to go to Window's Control Panel and search for Credentials. Then delete Gitlab's stored credentials and next time you do a Push in command line a popup will ask for username/password

Answer (score 0):

It seems your credentials for accessing git repository from jenkins are not working.
Please update your git credentials in jenkins